# How many APPLE_APFS partitions is a disk allowed to have?

Tags: macos, partition, diskutil, apfs

I am using macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.2.

### The following two examples indicate that a disk is only allowed one APPLE_APFS partition.

1. The output below from a Terminal application window shows that that

   ```
   diskutil partitiondisk disk1 2 gpt apfs Mac1 500g apfs Mac2 r
   ```

   command fails to create two APPLE_APFS partitions.

   ```
   Marlin:sbin davidanderson$ diskutil unmountdisk disk1
   Unmount of all volumes on disk1 was successful
   Marlin:sbin davidanderson$ diskutil partitiondisk disk1 2 gpt apfs Mac1 500g apfs Mac2 r
   You may not specify more than one APFS Container per partition map
   Marlin:sbin davidanderson$
   ```
2. The output below from a Terminal application window shows that both the

   ```
   diskutil apfs createcontainer disk1s3
   ```

   and

   ```
   diskutil apfs create disk1s3 Mac2
   ```

   commands fail to create a second APPLE_APFS partition.

   ```
   Marlin:sbin davidanderson$ diskutil list external
   /dev/disk1 (disk image):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.0 TB     disk1
      1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
      2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         500.0 GB   disk1s2
      3:                  Apple_HFS Mac2                    499.7 GB   disk1s3

   /dev/disk2 (synthesized):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk2
                                    Physical Store disk1s2
      1:                APFS Volume Mac1                    24.6 KB    disk2s1

   Marlin:sbin davidanderson$ diskutil apfs createcontainer disk1s3
   Creating container with disk1s3
   Started APFS operation on disk1s3 Mac2
   Creating a new empty APFS Container
   Error: -69615: At least one APFS Physical Store already exists on your partition map
   Marlin:sbin davidanderson$ diskutil apfs create disk1s3 Mac2
   Started APFS operation on disk1s3 Mac2
   Creating a new empty APFS Container
   Error: -69615: At least one APFS Physical Store already exists on your partition map
   Marlin:sbin davidanderson$
   ```

### The following example shows how to create two APPLE_APFS partitions on the same disk.

3. The output below from a Terminal application window shows that the

   ```
   diskutil apfs convert disk1s3
   ```

   command creates a second APPLE_APFS partition.

   ```
   Marlin:sbin davidanderson$ diskutil list external
   /dev/disk1 (disk image):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.0 TB     disk1
      1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
      2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         500.0 GB   disk1s2
      3:                  Apple_HFS Mac2                    499.7 GB   disk1s3

   /dev/disk2 (synthesized):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk2
                                    Physical Store disk1s2
      1:                APFS Volume Mac1                    24.6 KB    disk2s1

   Marlin:sbin davidanderson$ diskutil apfs convert disk1s3
   Started APFS operation on disk1s3 Mac2
   Converting HFS Volume to an APFS Container which will export one APFS Volume
   The target is the Journaled HFS+ volume "Mac2" backed by the GPT partition disk1s3
   The target is a data disk; it is not a macOS system disk
   Found APFS EFI driver /usr/standalone/i386/apfs.efi to install into the APFS Container
   The target is not encrypted
   Unmounting disk1s3
   Starting conversion from HFS to APFS
   Performing apfs_hfs_convert -x --verbose=0x400 --efi /usr/standalone/i386/apfs.efi /dev/disk1s3
   Reporting pre-conversion statistics
   Reporting post-conversion statistics
   Successfully finished conversion from HFS to APFS
   Successful conversion in commit mode so will switch type to APFS
   Setting type of disk1s3 to APFS
   Changing the physical disk partition type in shared mode
   Partition modification attempt count was 1
   Opening and closing disk1s3 to terminate old content driver
   Expecting the new APFS Container at Physical Store disk1s3
   Confirmed existence of new unencrypted APFS Volume disk3s1
   Mounting APFS Volume disk3s1
   APFS Volume mount attempt result was 0
   Exiting conversion operations with error code 0
   Disk from APFS operation: disk3s1
   Finished APFS operation on disk1s3 Mac2
   Marlin:sbin davidanderson$ diskutil list external
   /dev/disk1 (disk image):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.0 TB     disk1
      1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
      2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         500.0 GB   disk1s2
      3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         499.7 GB   disk1s3

   /dev/disk2 (synthesized):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk2
                                    Physical Store disk1s2
      1:                APFS Volume Mac1                    24.6 KB    disk2s1

   /dev/disk3 (synthesized):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +499.7 GB   disk3
                                    Physical Store disk1s3
      1:                APFS Volume Mac2                    32.8 KB    disk3s1

   Marlin:sbin davidanderson$
   ```

So, is there a bug in the commands that will not create a second APPLE_APFS partition?
Or, is the bug in the command that creates a second APPLE_APFS partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was posted early when APFS had just been released. The proper answer is one APFS partition per drive. While it is still possible to create more than one APFS partition, do so defeats the propose of using APFS.

Comment: Hi, Would you mind to review this please? Thanks in advance! https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/396301/finding-volume-label-and-understanding-the-apfs-partition