# Finding Volume Label and Understanding the APFS Partition

Tags: filesystem, apfs, macos

I would like to understand the Format Partition `APFS` on `Linux` Side.
I made this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597308

I have a USB External SSD with 4 disk partitions. The file system of partitions are

- `APFS`
- `ExFAT`
- `ext4`
- `NTFS`

Now I would like to find the Label (The Volume is named 'APFS') on my `APFS` partition....

[image]

Using the command `diskutil list` Can you see the `/dev/disk3`.
[image]

Checking the https://developer.apple.com/support/downloads/Apple-File-System-Reference.pdf

Here another blogs

1. https://blog.cugu.eu/post/apfs/
2. https://www.ntfs.com/apfs-structure.htm
3. https://digital-forensics.sans.org/media/FOR518-Reference-Sheet.pdf
4. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-030-98467-0_1.pdf *(last addition)*

Here a resume that I made of the First structure or Format Header of `APFS` Partition.
[image]

I would like the position of Label ('APFS' I named like File System) of my Volume.

Checking my First 4096 first bytes on my disk

[image]

At position `24(16) = 36(10)` (after `NXSB`) is located **`nx_block_size`** (4 bytes) used with value of `1000(16) = 4096(10)` bytes.
At position `28(16) = 40(10)` is located **`nx_block_count`** (8 bytes), here `37E0E80(16) = 58592896(10)`.

At position `68(16) = 104(10)` is located **`nx_xp_desc_blocks`** (4 bytes) used with value of `118(16) = 280(10)` blocks (the checkpoint descriptor area consists of 280 blocks).

At position `8C(16) = 140(10)` is located **`nx_xp_desc_len`** (4 bytes) used with value of `2(16) = 2(10)`.

(About the picture above)**Point 4:** What does it mean that `nx_efi_jumpstart_t` have `00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00`, where is there supposed to be an address?

[image]

(About the picture above)**Point 2:** `nx_xp_desc_base` How must be interpreted the bytes `45 81 00 00 | 00 00 00 00`?, is it a relative memory position or absolute memory position or Jump?

(About the picture above)**Point 6:** `nx_omap_oid` How must be interpreted the bytes `46 7e 09 00 | 00 00 00 00`?, is it a relative memory position or absolute memory position or Jump?

(About the picture above)**Point 7:** `nx_fs_oid` How must be interpreted the bytes `02 04 00 00 | 00 00 00 00`?, is it a relative memory position or absolute memory position or Jump?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Swiggity Swooty, that's some disk you've got their! Crazy thing, all that info you added and the ONE thing needed is `diskutil apfs list` :)

Comment: I made first checking on CentOS 8 may be making this Check on macOS have advantage over Linux where is the real target. I need to mount the AFPS with its label on Linux.

Comment: Perhaps I'm a bit tired, but isn't a label on a partition just a label that actually doesn't do anything? the UUID is what you should be after for each partition. Perhaps your partition map might be wrong for your task? Master boot record is what linux and windows prefer to read from... and apfs is still pretty new.

Comment: I'm reading manually with `Hexdump` directly on disk/partition. It doesn't matter if it's not mounted as `APFS`, I can still read it. I need to track manually because I want to implement a code in order to find the label on `Linux` Side.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/338063/194804